# Using lodash array functions on Restangular collections

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular, lodash

I'm using Restangular with AngularJS, and I would like to iterate over a collection in a function of the controller, where I need to modify a collection returned by Restangular:

```
var OrderController = [ '$scope', '$http', 'Restangular',
  function($scope, $http, Restangular) {
    $scope.orders = Restangular.all('orders').getList();
    $scope.toggleOrder = function(order) {
      _.forEach($scope.orders, function(order) {
        console.log(order); // This is not an order!
        order.someProperty = false; // My goal
      });
    });
  }];
```

I think the problem is that `$scope.orders` is a promise, not an actual array, so `_.forEach` tries to iterate on the properties of the promise instead of the objects. I get the same result with `angular.forEach`.

How can I iterate on Restangular resource collections? I'd like to have access to all collection functions of lodash, such as `_.filter`, as well.

Comment: Don't use forEach for something else than side-effects. Use map() here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Restangular.all('orders').getList()` - is a promise, not array.

Assign your list using `$object`:

```
$scope.orders = Restangular.all('orders').getList().$object;
```

List will be an empty array until request is complete.

**UPDATE** full code for question (includes orders modification on request complete)

```
$scope.orders = [];

function modifyOrders(orders){ ... }

Restangular.all('orders').getList().then(function(orders){
 modifyOrders(orders);
 $scope.orders=orders;
});

$scope.toggleOrders = function(toggledOrder){
 _.forEach($scope.orders, function(order) { ... });
};
```

Comment: But how can I modify the list once the request is complete?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var OrderController = [ '$scope', '$http', 'Restangular',
  function($scope, $http, Restangular) {

    $scope.toggleOrder = 
        Restangular.all('orders').getList().then(function(orders){
            _.forEach(orders, function(order) {
                console.log(order); // This is not an order!
                order.someProperty = false; // My goal
            });
        });
  }];
```

After getList() method you get the promise that takes the list in param.

From the docs : https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#using-self-reference-resources

Comment: This behaves differently: toggleOrder is invoked for all orders immediately after they are returned. My goal was to have a button invoke toggleOrder method on the clicked order.

Answer (score 0):

Even if accepted answer resolved the misunderstanding over arrays and promises, a problem remains...

`_.forEach` is ok but `_.filter` is not. Lodash strips Restangular collection methods.

Indeed

```
api.getList().then(function(items) {
  console.log(items.getRestangularUrl);
  items = _.filter(items, function() { return true; });
  console.log(items.getRestangularUrl);
));
```

results in

> log: function() {...}
>
> log: undefined

How to accomplish a filter preserving Restangular methods ?